# Terminator: Shortcuts for Prev and Next?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, search, terminal-emulator

In [terminator](https://launchpad.net/terminator), the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+F` opens up a small bar at the bottom of the window to let the user search a text string within the terminal scrollback.

Are there any keyboard shortcuts for moving to the **next** or **previous** matched item in this search? The most complete [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/terminator.1.html) I found for Terminator is included in the Ubuntu documentation, but it doesn't cover this topic in detail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may not be what you expect, nor was if for me, but it works (no mouse required)...  (btw: I've just started using Terminator, and so far I like it)..

A way to do it is to simply do this:

- If your active cursor is already in the *Find box*, just keep pressing `Enter` for **Next**.... and for **Prev**, press `Tab` to make the `Prev button` active an then just keep pressing `Enter`... the `Prev button` stays active, so it locates backwards each time you press enter..
- If your current active cursor in in the window body, just press Ctrl+Shift+F again, to get you back into the *Find box*, then just press Enter (next), or Tab, then Enter (prev)..

Also, you can switch between buttons, to reverse the search direction, via the Left and Right cursor(arrow) keys (I find that easier than Shift-Tab) ...

Comment: on terminator 2.1.3
`tab` hack is not working anymore